# How to convert B-Spline to piecewise polynomials?

Tags: splines, polynomial, interpolation

Suppose I have a basis spline $$ S(x) = \sum\limits_i N_{i,k} a_i $$ defined on the interval $x \in [a,b]$
with control points $a_i$, degree $k$. $N_i$ are the basis spline functions. The knot vector associated with $S$ is $t = [t_1, \dots, t_{n+p+1}]$.

What I want is to obtain the piecewise polynomial form
$$P_i(x) = b_i[x-x_i]^{k-1} + c_i[x-x_i]^{k-2} + \dots \quad x \in [x_i, x_{i+1}]$$
for each polynomial segment, i.e., the coefficients $b_i, c_i,\ldots$.

In scipy, for instance, this can be done using scipy.interpolate.PPoly class. What I am interested in are the equations behind it. So given control points + knot vector + spline order, how can I calculate the coefficients of the piecewise polynomials?

I found many similar questions here on the list, but none where actual equations are posted.
If I missed it, please point me to the right location.

Comment: Doesn't the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PPoly.html) give you an expression for the polynomial on each segment?

Comment: @ angryavian Do you mean P = (x-xi)^k + ... by expression? But this link does not explain *how* the coefficients are computed, does it?

Comment: There are conversion formulas.  Or just re-fit using a truncated power basis.

Comment: @ Frank Harrell Can you point me to a reference for the conversion formulas?

Comment: Also I was wondering how a re-fit works. Because there are more boundary conditions than degrees of freedom (coefficients of the polynomials). Can you comment on that again?